# Ошибка времени в datagridview

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, datagridview

Загружаю данные из ячеек  datagridview  в БД mysql. Все данные загружаются нормально кроме даты и времени. Ошибка в формате времени . В datagridview   она ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ,а нужна ГГГГ.ММ.ДД. Я попробовал конвертировать не получается . Кто может помочь?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
       
        for (int i = 0; i < OthetView.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            
               string thisDay = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("0000") + "." + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") + "." + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00"); //получаем строку вида ГГГГ.ММ.ДД
                for (int j = 0; j < OthetView.RowCount; j++)
                OthetView[1, i].Value = thisDay;
                CommandText = "INSERT INTO `othet`(Time,TABN,id_oper,Id_kass,Prixod,Rasxod) VALUES('" + Convert.ToDateTime(OthetView[1, i].Value) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(OthetView[2, i].Value) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(OthetView[3, i].Value) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(OthetView[4, i].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(OthetView[5, i].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(OthetView[6, i].Value) + "');";
        }
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Сохранено");
    }
```

Comment: Используйте универсальлный формат даты, а не руссифицированный yyyy-MM-dd. `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`. И вы из комментария про конкатенацию строк запроса к вашему прошлому вопросу кажется ничего не усвоили. Зря игнорируете, как-будто я вам какую-то чушь посоветовал.

Comment: Я не игнорирую ,просто немного не въехал в тему.

Comment: Я ж вам ссылку с кодом дал. Там прямой пример как надо делать.

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться